# Nulls after each character when writing CString to CFile using Write member

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently studying MFC library CFile class and I have a problem with writing data to a file using Write method. When I pass char array as parameter it works perfectly fine:

```
char c[] = "Hello!"; 
int size = sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]);
myFile.Write(c, size)
```

Characters that were written to file:

```
Hello!
```

But when I try to pass CString object as an argument:

```
CString cS("Hello");
myFile.Write(cS, cS.GetLength());
```

I get:

```
H e l
```

I also tried:

```
CString cS("Hello");
LPWSTR c = cS.GetBuffer();
myFile.Write(c, cS.GetLength());
cS.ReleaseBuffer();
```

But the output is the same as above. What may be cause that conversion? Does it happen because text is stored in wide characters?

Comment: Use `CStringA` instead of `CString`. Wide characters in the ASCII range consist of one byte ASCII and one null byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

The second parameter to [CFile::Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b2eb5757-d499-4e67-b044-dd7d1abaa0f8.aspx#cfile__write) is the number of bytes that the function will transfer from the first parameter (the buffer). You're passing `cS.GetLength()`, which would rather pass the number of characters in the string, and this is not the same as the number of bytes that the string itself may be composed of.

**Solution:**

You should change the line that writes the string into file to something like this:

```
myFile.Write(LPCTSTR(cS), cS.GetLength()*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

`sizeof(TCHAR)` will yield a different number based on if you're building for Unicode or MBCS. This is because `TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t` for Unicode builds, and as `char` for MBCS builds. As such, multiplying the length of string with the size of TCHAR will *always* equal the number of bytes the string is composed of regardless of if you're building for Unicode or not.

**Other points to note:**

You've no reason to call `GetBuffer()` and `ReleaseBuffer()` here, whatsoever.

This point is not a major, but the `CFile::Write` function takes a `const void *` as its first argument. So you should rather be casting your `CString` to `LPCTSTR` (which would automatically evaluate to `LPCWSTR` or `LPCSTR` based on if you're building with Unicode or MBCS).

One last thing: It's good to wrap string literals with the `_T()` macro so that you could compile for Unicode and MBCS alike without having to change your code.

Applying all changes, your whole code would look something like this:

```
CString cS(_T("Hello"));
myFile.Write(LPCTSTR(cS), cS.GetLength()*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Comment: Semantically, `sizeof(TCHAR)` should rather be `sizeof(cS::XCHAR)`. That's the predefined character type for all `CStringT`-derived string types. I would also recommend against explicitly casting. The conversion operator is implicitly invoked. If you want to be explicit, you could call it's `GetString()` member instead. Doing so prevents inadvertently invoking a conversion operator.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't think you could type `sizeof(cS::XCHAR)` and have it compile. I think you probably meant `sizeof(CString::XCHAR)`, but that's going to be the exact same thing as `sizeof(TCHAR)`. Also, note that `LPCTSTR` is actually an operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: *"I think you probably meant `sizeof(CString::XCHAR)`, but that's going to be the exact same thing as `sizeof(TCHAR)`."* - That's true, they designate the same type. However, there is a semantic difference: While `TCHAR` is merely an unrelated type, `XCHAR` is the type that's used throughout the `CString` implementation. *"Also, note that `LPCTSTR` is actually an operator"* - That's why I called it *"conversion operator"* previously. It's still implicitly invoked. Correct link to documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sddk80xf.aspx#csimplestringt__operator_pcxstr).

Comment: Take special note, that there is no `operator LCPTSTR()` (as there used to be with the Visual Studio 6 implementation). It's called [`operator PXSTR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sddk80xf.aspx#csimplestringt__operator_pcxstr), so your code is only correct by accident. It fails in case client code explicitly uses a character string's encoding, that doesn't coincide with the definition of `TCHAR` (e.g. `CStringW` in a project that doesn't have `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` defined).

Comment: *"I don't think you could type `sizeof(cS::XCHAR)` and have it compile."* - Correct, I meant to write `sizeof( decltype( cS )::XCHAR )`. That **always** returns the correct size of a character code unit for any given `CString` instance, irrespective of project settings. This is important, since you can use `CStringA` in a Unicode project, or `CStringW` in an MBCS project, so `sizeof( TCHAR )` would yield the wrong value.

Comment: @IInspectable too bad `CString` didn't define a constant member equal to `sizeof(XCHAR)`, it would have made this a lot easier.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That would have gone against `CString`'s ultimate design goal: Being a true drop-in replacement for C-style strings. To meet that, `CString` must maintain, that `sizeof(CString)` equals `sizeof(void*)`. Adding instance variables breaks this invariant. A workable alternative would have been to introduce a `GetStringSize()` member, but *"convenience"* is likely not strong enough of an incentive to break the ABI.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're compiling with `UNICODE` defined, and `CString` is a string of wide characters, each of which occupies two bytes.  What's getting written to your file is what you're seeing as the character byte, followed by a zero byte.

Comment: Worth an edit to explicitly state that `GetLength` will return the number of characters, not the number of bytes, and thus half of what `Write` requires.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing in MFC, Visual C++ 6.0 to Visual C++ 2005 for about 4 years now professionally to support our companies applications.

In my experiences and what I know of the `CString` class objects, they are always `NULL` terminated.  This can cause different behavior than using a character array, but is not the problem above.

I believe your problem to be related to the buffer you are passing in as an argument.  `LPWSTR` is a 32-bit pointer to a string of 16-bit characters per this [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx).

From what I can tell based on what you posted, you are outputting 16 bit `Unicode` characters and viewing them as `ANSI`hence this behavior would be expected.  If you were to open your notepad file as `Unicode`, you would not see the spaces.

Alternatively, if you build your project using `ANSI` character set, or convert to `ANSI` prior to writing to the file, the spaces should go away when you open the output in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TCHAR c[] = "Hello!"; 
int charCount = sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]);
myFile.Write(c, charCount*sizeof(c[0]));
```

Write will write only number of bytes specified. charCount will be same as number of bytes for ASCII, but will be half the value for UNICODE.

Try changing above code for your type of text

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6337eske.aspx